# How to get mimeData for multiple selected rows in drag Action in QAbstractTableModel?

Tags: pyqt

I have a QAbstractTableModel, which is the model for a TableView that enables multiple row selections. However, on the mimeData method for the model, the index list only returns each column value for a single row. How can I get all the other rows?

Comment: What is your TableView's selection mode and selection behavior?

Comment: MultiSelection with Extended Selection.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve the selected rows, you should access the [selectionModel()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qabstractitemview.html#selectionModel) of the table view:

```
QList< int > getSelectedRows( QTableView* tableView )
{
    QList< int > selectedRows;

    if( !tableView || !tableView->selectionModel() ) return selectedRows;

    QModelIndexList selectedRowIndices = tableView->selectionModel()->selectedRows();
    foreach( QModelIndex index, selectedRowIndices )
    {
        selectedRows.append( index.row() );
    }

    return selectedRows;
}
```

Comment: That kind of works, but I have multiple views associated with that same model. Im doing this in pyqt so it might be different, but I'm trying to get the selection from the mimeData method of the model itself. Is there a way to get the view thats providing the selection from inside the model implementation? Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Ok, so I've passed an argument of the view object to the model, so then I can reference the view selectionModel from within it.

Comment: Ah didn't see you were using python. Anyway, why would you put code like that into your model? There are different selections possible in the different views, but there is only one model. A model should never need to know where it is displayed.